# TeamCity Kotlin DSL: how to run a PowerShell script from file located in the DSL folder

Tags: powershell, kotlin, teamcity, dsl

I have a build configuration defined in a repository that builds projects in other repositories.
Some of the steps are powershell, and currently, i wrote all the logic in the Kotlin file itself, but it is kinda hard to read and maintain. 
I though it will be easier to work in this scripts if they are separated .ps1 files. I know there is an option to run scripts in files if you provide the path like:

```
powerShell { 
    scriptMode = file { 
        path = "path\to\file.ps1"
    }
}
```

Problem is, when the step runs, it says it cannot find the `.teamcity` folder, where they are located. I cannot add them to the other repos because some of the scripts are needed in several projects.

Is it possible to access that folder from that step or should i continue working with the messy inline scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to the documentation, there is a way to read files [within the .teamcity folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/kotlin-dsl.html#KotlinDSL-HowtoReadFilesinKotlinDSL). However, that is only in the DSL context. That won't work to define a script path because at the time that portion of code is run, that code doesn't exists (i tried `ls` workdir). So what you have to do is to explicitly checkout the folder. To do that, you have to define [checkout rules](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/dsl-documentation/jetbrains.build-server.configs.kotlin.v2019_2/-vcs-settings/root.html) like:

```
vcs {
    root(VCS)
    root(DslContext.settingsRoot, "+:.teamcity/scripts => tcscripts", "+:Configurations => configurations")
    cleanCheckout = true
}
```

That will checkout the scripts folder within `.teamcity` in a folder called `tscripts` in the root of the workdir. You can of course change the directories and add more rules. After that, you will be able to call them in the steps like:

```
powerShell {
    formatStderrAsError = true
    scriptMode = file {
        path = "tcscripts/your_script.ps1"
    }
}
```